# Javascript RegExp for cellphone with specifics code area

Tags: jquery, plugins, input, mask

Im using jQuery Mask Plugin (http://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/) to mask an input for a cellphone with code area.

```
$('.cellphone').mask('00 000000000');
```

This accepts inputs like:

> 21 972389472
>
> 99 232441244
>
> 69 522235352
>
> 42 022222222

But now I have to match specifics code area. For example, only code areas 21 and 99 are allowed. So with the same input would accepts only:

> 21 972389472
>
> 99 232441244

Im trying to create a mask function, but not having much success. The plugin offers this functionality, like:

```
var celphoneMask = function(phone, e, currentField, options){
  return phone.match(/^(\(?11\)? ?9(5[0-9]|6[0-9]|7[01234569]|8[0-9]|9[0-9])[0-9]{1})/g) ? 
  '(00) 00000-0000' : '(00) 0000-0000';
};

$(".sp_celphones").mask(celphoneMask);
```

Any idea how can I do this? :s

Answer (score 0):

The following regular expression will accept 21..... and 99..... Numbers.

```
/^(?:21|99) [0-9]{8}$/
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no apparent option for preventing multiple-digit patterns from appearing using this plugin as the `Regex` testing is "per character". You can still only accept valid area codes, but you have to work outside the plugin.

You can eliminate the bulk of invalid area codes with the plugin by using the `translation` option to customize a digit pattern:

```
"translation": {
    "y": {
        "pattern": /[29]/,
            "optional": false
    },
    "z": {
        "pattern": /[19]/,
            "optional": false
    }
}
```

which then makes your mask:

```
'yz 000000000'
```

This will only accept area codes `21`, `29`, `91`, and `99`. To prevent `29`, and  `91`, you need to trap the `keypress` event and test for those two combinations. I would love to be able to say that you can use the `onKeyPress` plugin option, but the plugin actually fires the `onKeyPress` option `onKeyUp`, not `onKeyPress`. The good news is that you can chain your own `onKeyPress` handler to the `mask` plugin:

```
$(selector).mask().on('keypress', function (e) {
    var validAreaCodes = /^(?:21|99)/, // define area codes
        value = this.value + String.fromCharCode(e.which), // append keypressed to existing value
        matched = validAreaCodes.test(value), // test new value
        failed = value.length > 1 && !matched; // fail if not a match
    if (failed) {
        e.preventDefault(); // prevent keypress if failed
    };
    return !failed;
});
```

### Here's a working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/K9YF4/